# python odometry

Tags: python, navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe I should have reread the navigation tutorials before making that last post. What I really need is good example on how to publish the odometry in python given that I have already amount the robot has travelled in the x and y axis between the last publishing and the current publishing and the current angle the robot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79851/python-odometry/) by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-09-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, odometry has to be published in **fixed frame**. So, you need to accumulate x, y and orientation (yaw).

Following is the stripped snippet from a working node. Please do appropriate modifications to suit your application needs.

Matrix `P` is a covariance matrix from EKF with [x, y, yaw] system state. Description of [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) may be helpful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import rospy
import roslib
import tf
import PyKDL as kdl

# Messages
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point, Quaternion

roslib.load_manifest('odom_publisher')

class RosOdomPublisher:
  gps_ekf_odom_pub = rospy.Publisher('/odom', Odometry)
  tf_br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()

  publish_odom_tf = True

  frame_id = '/odom'
  child_frame_id = '/base_footprint'

  # Covariance
  P = np.mat(np.diag([0.0]*3))

  def publish_odom(self):
      msg = Odometry()
      msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
      msg.header.frame_id = self.frame_id # i.e. '/odom'
      msg.child_frame_id = self.child_frame_id # i.e. '/base_footprint'
    
      msg.pose.pose.position = Point(self.x, self.y, self.z)
      msg.pose.pose.orientation = Quaternion(*(kdl.Rotation.RPY(R, P, Y).GetQuaternion()))
    
      p_cov = np.array([0.0]*36).reshape(6,6)
    
      # position covariance
      p_cov[0:2,0:2] = self.P[0:2,0:2]
      # orientation covariance for Yaw
      # x and Yaw
      p_cov[5,0] = p_cov[0,5] = self.P[2,0]
      # y and Yaw
      p_cov[5,1] = p_cov[1,5] = self.P[2,1]
      # Yaw and Yaw
      p_cov[5,5] = self.P[2,2]
    
      msg.pose.covariance = tuple(p_cov.ravel().tolist())

      pos = (msg.pose.pose.position.x,
             msg.pose.pose.position.y,
             msg.pose.pose.position.z)

      ori = (msg.pose.pose.orientation.x,
             msg.pose.pose.orientation.y,
             msg.pose.pose.orientation.z,
             msg.pose.pose.orientation.w)

      # Publish odometry message
      self.gps_ekf_odom_pub.publish(msg)

      # Also publish tf if necessary
      if self.publish_odom_tf:
          self.tf_br.sendTransform(pos, ori, msg.header.stamp, msg.child_frame_id, msg.header.frame_id)

      ...
```

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on 2013-09-16**:
I understand most of the code but the portion between position covariance comment and lining reading msg.pose.covariance=tuple(P_cov.rave1().tolist()) has me mystified what is it for

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-09-16**:
You can ignore this part. It simply converts covariance matrix for [x, y, yaw] to [x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw].

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-16**:
Did you work out how to use this